# Update sql query with condition

Tags: sql

I have two Tables:
Average Table

```
LSP Runid
ABC_XYZ 123
DEF_XYZ 456
```

Data Table

```
LSP Runid
RECON_ABC_XYZ 
RECON_DEF_XYZ
```

My query is :

```
UPDATE DATA INNER JOIN
       AVERAGE
       ON DATA.LSP = AVERAGE.LSP
    SET DATA.Runid = AVERAGE.Runid
```

I am unable to update my data table

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Your `Average` table doesn't have `LSP`, so this logic will not work in any database.

Comment: Average table has LSP values ABC_XYZ and DEF_XYZ

Answer (score 0):

The LSP data doesn't match. You will need to add RECON_ to the AVERAGE table to match the records in the DATA table. Assuming they all begin with RECON_ you can use the following query in SQL Server 2012 +

```
UPDATE DATA INNER JOIN
   AVERAGE
   ON DATA.LSP = CONCAT('RECON_', AVERAGE.LSP)
SET DATA.Runid = AVERAGE.Runid
```

Comment: Do you really mean "SQL **Server** 2012+"?  Because there is no SQL standard 2012 - which "SQL 2012"  would refer to.